# Column index not updating in SQL Server 2008

Tags: performance, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

I had asked a question on stackoverflow:
[Large SQL Server database timing out PHP web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460602/large-mssql-database-timing-out-php-web-application)

The problem was that the query was fast for when a previous date was chosen and slow for a more current date. We fixed it by recreating the index and hence it worked. For a while I thought the index might have gotten corrupted.

Today the issue occurred again (slow) and by recreating it again it ran fast. This was done on the date column which is of type datetime.

Is there a specific reason for this or is the SQL Server 2008 R2 corrupted?

Comment: Could you post the code for the index?

Comment: Indexes need to be **maintained** - do you have a maintenance plan in place that e.g. rebuilds the indexes and their statistics every night?

Comment: i always thought it auto updates. Guess i need to check that again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [UPDATE STATISTICS (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx)

> Updates query optimization statistics on a table or indexed view. By
>   default, the query optimizer already updates statistics as necessary
>   to improve the query plan; in some cases you can improve query
>   performance by using UPDATE STATISTICS or the stored procedure
>   [sp_updatestats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173804.aspx) to update statistics more frequently than the default
>   updates.

```
UPDATE STATISTICS table_or_indexed_view_name 
    [ 
        { 
            { index_or_statistics__name }
          | ( { index_or_statistics_name } [ ,...n ] ) 
                }
    ] 
    [    WITH 
        [ 
            FULLSCAN 
            | SAMPLE number { PERCENT | ROWS } 
            | RESAMPLE 
            | <update_stats_stream_option> [ ,...n ]
        ] 
        [ [ , ] [ ALL | COLUMNS | INDEX ] 
        [ [ , ] NORECOMPUTE ] 
    ] ;

<update_stats_stream_option> ::=
    [ STATS_STREAM = stats_stream ]
    [ ROWCOUNT = numeric_constant ]
    [ PAGECOUNT = numeric_contant ]
```

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is not corrupted. This never happens. It might be fragmented or have a lot wasted space. This is normal. It happens because of certain write patterns.

Rebuilding is a good countermeasure. You can try reorganizing as an alternative.